# Did Dumbledore know there would be a possible inside job?

Tags: harry-potter

I ask this due to the search procedures during the sixth film. Along with this, Dumbledore has a speech regarding Tom Riddle, which highlights a very key quote.

> Now as you know, each and every one of you was searched upon your arrival here tonight and you have the right to know why. Once there was a young man, who like you, sat in this very hall, walked this castle's corridors, slept under its roofs. He seemed to all the world a student like any other. His name: Tom Riddle. Today, of course, he's known all over the world by another name, which is why, as I stand looking out upon you all tonight, I'm reminded of a sobering fact: Every day, every hour, this very minute, perhaps, dark forces attempt to penetrate this castle's walls. But in the end, **their greatest weapon... is you**.
>
> - Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Film

Was Dumbledore having his students searched because he thought there could be an inside job? If so, why? As he already knew of Malfoy's plans, it doesn't seem right.

Comment: @randal'thor You saw nothing. ;)

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but as you say, it doesn't seem quite right. Are we sure it was Dumbledore who ordered the searching of students, or could it be, say, a Ministry-enforced procedure?

Comment: @randal'thor Never thought of that. Dumbledore just seems to be in so much power of his school - and, I believe he is now on speaking terms with the Minister after he saw Voldemort. As he had the power to keep Sirius in the Charms room, and keep Sybill at Hogwarts - my guess would be it was him.

Comment: Also, where does that quote originate - book or film? Could just be a film goof-up.

Comment: I have thought a lot on that line and now I think maybe he means *you* are *this castle's* greatest weapon. Eg if the students are all vigilant, the castle is safe.

Comment: i mean, increased security seems pretty resonable since voldemorte is back. Despite the fact dumbeldore knows about malfoy any of the other kids in slytherin could smuggle stuff in, or any other kid under the imperious curse

Comment: I also think this scene is meant to illustrate how you can never blindly trust a massive group of people - there are all the things @Himarm mentioned and others like children of known Death Eaters amongst the students.

Answer (score 5):

The searching was not done because Dumbledore knew Malfoy would target him. It was done for the general protection of the students of Hogwarts. As you know, by the start of the sixth book(movie), Voldemort has revealed his return to the world. So it is safe to presume he would begin his plans to take over the wizarding world. The children of many Death Eaters still attended Hogwarts. Voldemort might try to cause havoc by using these children to harm the others in Hogwarts. Also, many children's parents can be blackmailed by threatening harm to their children in Hogwarts. This is just another step towards ensuring safety of all people in the school.

Of course, toward the end of the seventh book we come to know that Dumbledore did know of Malfoy's plans to kill him. He informs Snape to help Malfoy and make sure no one else is accidentally harmed when Malfoy tries executing his plans. This is because he realizes he will die within a year anyway, due to the curse held by the ring Horcrux(which was also the Resurrection Stone). We see this in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 33: *The Prince's Tale*

> Dumbledore smiled.
>   “I refer to the plan Lord Voldemort is revolving around me. His plan to have
>   the poor Malfoy boy murder me.”
>
> Snape sat down in the chair Harry had so often occupied, across the desk from Dumbledore. Harry could tell that he wanted to say more on the subject of
>   Dumbledore’s cursed hand, but the other held it up in polite refusal to discuss the matter further. Scowling, Snape said, “The Dark Lord does not expect Draco to succeed. This is merely punishment for Lucius’s recent failures. Slow torture for Draco’s parents, while they watch him fail and pay the price.”
>
> “In short, the boy has had a death sentence pronounced upon him as surely
>   as I have,” said Dumbledore. “Now, I should have thought the natural successor
>   to the job, once Draco fails, is yourself?”
>
> There was a short pause.
>
> “That, I think, is the Dark Lord’s plan.”
>
> ...
>
> “Good. Now then. Your first priority will be to discover what Draco is up to.
>   A frightened teenage boy is a danger to others as well as to himself. Offer him help and guidance, he ought to accept, he likes you—”
>
> “—much less since his father has lost favor. Draco blames me, he thinks I
>   have usurped Lucius’s position.”
>
> “All the same, try. I am concerned less for myself than for accidental victims
>   of whatever schemes might occur to the boy. Ultimately, of course, there is only one thing to be done if we are to save him from Lord Voldemort’s wrath.”
>
> Snape raised his eyebrows and his tone was sardonic as he asked, “Are you
>   intending to let him kill you?”
>
> “Certainly not. You must kill me.”

So, the searching of students was not for Dumbledore's own protection, but the protection of the students and staff of Hogwarts in general.